# Executing a piece of code on every ajax request

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-ajax

I am working on an ASP.net forms project. On every ajax request, I need to execute a piece of code (in this case, resetting the session expiry). What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: On the front-end or the back-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of global AJAX events that happen during the lifecycle of an AJAX request: before a request is sent is one of them. You can use that to set a handler that runs every time ANY AJAX call is made in your page.

This might help [ASP.NET Ajax Life Cycle](http://ezzylearning.com/CheatSheets/MS%20ASP.net%20Ajax%20Client%20Life-Cycle%20Events.pdf)

Comment: In global.aspx, I implemented the following method

 Sub Application_EndRequest(sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If (Session("_UserID")) Is Nothing Then
            Session.Timeout = 60 * 24 '24 hours
        End If
 End Sub

But unfortunately, It does not allow me to access Session Variable here and the error is "Session state is not available in this context". 
Any Advise?

Comment: Sounds like you have a scoping issue. I am not an ASP coder so cannot say what for sure, but you need to pass the session into the callback method by ref

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a wrapper over ajax request, which you will be calling from user code
2. Assuming you are using something like jQuery ajax, which returns a Promise, chain your _always_run_this_function_ to the success handler, and then return.

Since a promise can have any number of handlers, 1) your common function and 2) user function will run in sequence.

```
   function AjaxWrapper(webMethodName, parameterListInJsonFormat) {  
       var promise = $.ajax({  
          url: "Service.svc/" + webMethodName,  
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
          type: "POST",  
           input: parameterListInJsonFormat  
         });  
         promise.done(_always_run_this_function_);
         return promise;
    }
```

Details: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/636701/jQuery-Promise-An-introduction-to-AJAX-with-multic

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax intercepter,

```
$.ajaxSetup({
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    /// call your method here
}});
```